# Translate "self-made" into both an adjective and a noun

Tags: classical-latin, english-to-latin-translation

I'm looking to translate the phrase "self-made" into an adjective and a noun. Unlike the English phrase where "made" doesn't mean you literally made yourself, in this case I want it to actually mean that you created yourself. In regards to a noun, the context is a group of people that created themselves, so they would call themselves "the self-made".

Answer (score 4):

Unless you specifically want a Latin compound, the Greek-based terms *autogenous* (adj.), *autogene* (n.) suggest themselves. Some Googling shows they're already in existence with more or less the meaning you want.

Comment: I like the simplicity and ease that this would be understood. The adjective was easy enough to find, although the noun mostly brought up some german-language results. I might be able to work with _autogene_ and add a suffix the imply further meaning, though.

Comment: I did some poking around and found [Autogenitor](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/autogenitor), which seems like it even more closely aligns with the idea of making/creating oneself. It's not clear to me from the citation on that when it was actually used, although I might use that as the "first" of these people.

Answer (score 2):

*A se factus* is both an adjective and a noun, as indeed are all Latin adjectives. It literally means "having been made by himself". *A se facta* is the feminine version of the same noun.

One possible problem with this is that *a se factus* has to be a third person noun. You can't really say, "I am *a se factus*." You have to say *a me factus sum*. The same goes for "you". Whether this is a problem depends entirely on how you mean to use this noun.

You may object that this is a noun *phrase* and that you want a noun *simpliciter*. In that case, I don't see why you couldn't prepend *sui-* to make *sui-factus*, along the lines of *sui-cida* (self-killer).

Comment: Sui-factus is definitely closer to what I am looking for, although _sui_ could be somewhat of a loaded word to some people because of closeness to suicide. The phrase _a me factus sum'_ is perfect, though.